# How to import excel to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, excel, database, csv, import

How can I import an Excel file containing data from three different tables with foreign keys into a mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do it is working with `Excel` itself. In order to help you we need more details about the Tables in the excel and the tables in the database but you will get it:

Make a new column and using formulas with `CONCATENATE`, do a sample "`INSERT INTO`" command. Use `series` for do the INSERT's automatically, copy & paste the column into a .`sql` file and execute it.

If you need more detail, if you edit your question and I will glade to help you improving this answer.